# How do i print each line in a .txt file one by one in a while loop in python

Tags: python

Ok so, lets say i have data from a .txt file here:

```
ToddShields74

GeorgeGutierrez18

ReginaHenry71

JohnBlair34

PaigeKirby47

...
```

Now, i want a python code that will print each line one by one in a loop, for example:

```
while/if (imagine some random thing here):
print(line1 of the text file)
```

(obviously not a real code but presenting what i need.)

Then the next loop should print the next line, and the next, until it has printed all the lines in the file

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: Please update the question with the research you’ve already carried out. Where *exactly* do you need help? Happy to help with *specific* questions; yet not willing to just hand out code, without seeing diligent effort on your part.

Comment: This is very basic stuff. You're much better off going through some tutorials than posting here. You can [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) files, iterate with a for loop and [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open the file and iterate through it:

```py
file_name = "file.txt"

with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip()) # strip to remove extra newline after each line
        # whatever else you want to do
```